# Infinite amount of rediretcs with .htaccess in subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, web, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get a webpage running which might not get any support anymore, so I have to fix this on my own. So in the root directory, I have this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*) resources/$1 [L]
```

So all the content gets redirected to the `resources/` folder. Now this kinda works, as the frontpage shows all the static content (CSS, JS, Images). But when I try to open `mydomain.com/admin`, I'll get an `HTTP 500`. The logfile says

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

The `.htaccess` file in the sub-dir has this content:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?param=$1 [QSA,L]
```

For my basic Apache knowledge this does seems quite right; but is it, or do I have change Apache settings? (The VPS is a kind of PaaS-thing, so I can access/change some things)

Thank you.

Comment: I dare say that the requests that work (CSS.JS, images) are actually cached on the client side. Because requests to such URLs will certainly also run into a rewriting loop...

Comment: @arkascha when I first tried to run the webpage, the statics didn't work; then I put in the RewriteBase \ line in and then it worked. I never visited the webpage before that.

Answer (score 1):

Have your root htaccess rule file in following way(you need to put a condition for a check before rewriting).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/resources [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ resources/$1 [L]
```

Then for your sub directory level htaccess file try following:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?param=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Also in case you want to apply same rules which you have in your root directory to sub-directories then add `RewriteOptions InheritBefore` before `RewriteEngine ON` in your sub directory level htaccess file.

Comment: @wernersbacher, oh sorry there was a typo in it, Amit has fixed now, could you please try with new rules once and let me know how it goes. THANKS Amit for fixing typo.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but still the same error. Did you intend to alter the .htaccess file for the the subdir, as this file is still the same?

Comment: @wernersbacher, no I meant to change the root htaccess file, there were NO changes in sub directory htaccess, kindly do make changes in root one and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to be sure :) I don't know what else to change in the root .htaccess, but it seems like the .htaccess of the sub-dir is not the problem?

Comment: @wernersbacher, yeah sub directory htaccess looks ok to me.